# Sort with VBA - Multi level sorting

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a custom list (there is only one custom list) for sorting in Excel
I sort first by : Column A (date) ascending 
Column H (Letters "H," "A," "B") custom list 
Column G (date) descending

But get a wrong result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQnYV.png)

```
Sub Sort()
Dim LRow As Long

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("H", "A", "B")

    With Sheets("Basis")
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Names.Add Name:="Daten", RefersTo:=.Range("A1:H" & LRow)
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Range("Daten").Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Range("Daten").Sort key1:=.Range("H1"), order1:=xlDescending, ordercustom:=Application. _
     CustomListCount + 1, Header:=xlYes
    .Range("Daten").Sort key1:=.Range("G1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
     End With

    Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount

End Sub
```

Correct Sorting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx2kw.png)

Comment: Hmm - you may have to add the correct sorting picture again. I thought I edited the question correctly, but it looks like the two screenshots are identical.

Comment: Why `CustomListCount + 1` ?  Try following this general pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619676/sort-multiple-columns-excel-vba   Add the sort fields before calling `Sort`

Comment: This is not the same result

Comment: "This is not the same result"  - what is *this*? And what is it not the same as?  Please try to be a little more detailed in your responses, or it's difficult to offer any help.

Comment: Thanks for your support Ted, the sorting should be as in the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim v As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("H", "A", "B")
    v = Application.CustomListCount

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Basis")

    With Ws
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("h" & LRow))
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("h1"), Order:=xlDescending, CustomOrder:=v
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("g1"), Order:=xlDescending
        With .Sort
            .SetRange rngDB
            .Header = xlYes
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
    Application.DeleteCustomList v
End Sub
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: @CanUlucan - you're getting your names mixed up. This answer is from Dy.Lee, not Francis, and you also said Ted instead of Tim in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028571/sort-with-vba-multi-level-sorting/62028748#comment109718662_62028571)

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee, Thx., great Job!