# Sorting alphabetically two columns, first one contains a set of repeat values and the second are unique values

Tags: excel, vba

How can I sort to columns in the following way

My two columns before sorting

```
C    Ciks
C    Bsdjnf
C    ACfff
A    Bhdh
A    Apdp
A    Cyay
B    Ayay
B    Cnan
B    Btag
```

After being sorted

```
A    Apdp
A    Bhdh
A    Cyay
B    Ayay
B    Btag
B    Cnan
C    ACfff
C    Bsdjnf
C    Ciks
```

I have been using the common command found for example [sort multiple columns excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619676/sort-multiple-columns-excel-vba)
but when sorting the second column, this modified the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sort Multiple Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortMultipleColumns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rg.Columns(1), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rg.Columns(2), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange rg
        .Header = xlNo ' usually you have headers, then use 'xlYes'
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have a header but I have a empty first row so I guess I have. Let me try and I will come back to you soon

Comment: Then use `A2` instead of `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it excel? Can't you use excel Data -> Sort?
[image]

It will sort by priority, upper line, upper priority, then next line... will not modify prior sorted line(s).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is part of a application I am doing so it need to be by using a macro. But thanks now, I know how to do this manually too.

Comment: I mean you can try a recording macro while you are doing this in manual, then recorded script can show you some hints with interesting parameters :D. Anyway, someone helped you with this.